# EventHandler in external java file not getting triggered

Tags: spring-boot, axon

I have an `Aggregate` class which has

1. `CommandHandler` that receives a `CreateAccountCommand`
2. 1 `EventSourceHandling` that receives `AccountCreatedEvent`

Correspondingly, in other package, I’ve `@EventHandler` for the `AccountCreatedEvent`. However, it is not getting invoked.

```java
@Component
class EventHandlingComponent {

  @Autowired AccountRepository repo; 

  @EventHandler
  public void on(AccountCreatedEvent event ) 
  {
    // save to repository ; 
  }
}
```

I’m using spring boot application with this added as dependency

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.axonframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>axon-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.3</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.axonframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>axon-server-connector</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

I'll be really thankful if someone can point me what mistake I'm making.

Comment: How are you checking it is not getting invoked? Can we see your configurations (`@Bean`s you created and properties files)? The best would be a small reproduceable of this behaviour in a form of a github project.

Comment: @LucasCampos this is the project url https://github.com/gks-96/axon-framework-demo. 
In this demo, i'm able to call the event handler but in one of my another applications ( not possible to share that code) , event handler function is not getting called. That's why i asked what can be the most probable causes for the same.

Answer (score 1):

Is the event handler class in a package that is a subpackage from the package of the main class? If not, the scanner will not find the class by default. In this case you will have to configure which packages Spring boot should scan (using the scanBasePackages property in the SpringBootApplication annotation).

Comment: thanks for the reply ,  yes , i've taken care of that .